# Write to a file but conversion cannot be done

Tags: c#, php

I have a php code like this and I need to convert it to .Net

```
$A = array_keys($_GET);
$f1 = fopen("doc\\outputreport.txt",'w');
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($A); $i++) {
$args = $A[$i]."=".konvertering($_GET[ $A[$i] ], "ISO8859-1", "UTF-8");
fwrite($f1, $args."\r\n");
}
```

Here is my conversion:

```
  string fileOut = ((Request.QueryString["msisdn"] )+ (Request.QueryString["shortcode"]) + (Request.QueryString["password"]).ToString());
        try
        {
            Filestream filestream = new Filestream(@"\\outputreport.txt",  FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write,FileMode.Append);

        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Values comes from another page via a query string. In this file I write converted values.UTF-8 to ISO.I have another function called konvertering to convert characters from UTF 8 to ISO.but i'm not handle that part here..is this partial part correct ? how can i do that part.. give me a solution or clue

Comment: You just want to write file using c sharp code or anything else here ?

Comment: I tried to edit it to make it more understandable but I don't understand the last part, please fix it so we can know what are you talking about.

Comment: i mean for the values comes from another file using query string.what is the unclear part.this is C#

Comment: I know check my answer.Is this helpful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it works for you as per your question :

```
 string fileOut = ((Request.QueryString["msisdn"] )+ (Request.QueryString["shortcode"]) + (Request.QueryString["password"]).ToString());

string mydocpath = 
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string txtName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mydocpath,"outputreport.txt")) 
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtName))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(fileOut);
            sb.AppendLine("= = = = = =");
            sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

    }

    using (StreamWriter outfile = 
        new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\outputreport.txt"))
    {
        outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: To make flexible your code.If you run your exe file on another machine then it will get exact path where MYDocument folder reside in that machine

Answer (score 2):

I have never used PHP but if you are just trying to write to a file then it would probably be better to use

[System.IO.File.AppendAllText(string path, string contents);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx)